# Computer algebra system for category theory

Tags: category-theory, computer-algebra-systems

There are many different computer algebra systems which allows to perform computer aided computation in symbolic object like polynomials and function and also ordinals. 
Now being a category theory fanatic I'm wondering if there's any such system which can perform calculation in any 2-category. So.......

> does anyone know a computer algebra system which can perform calculation with 2-categories and or string diagrams?

Answer (score 3):

Pretty sure it is not exactly what you're looking for, but [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/) is designed in an categorical way (for instance, a group is an instance of the subclass Groups of the class Monoids, which is in turn a subclass of the class Magmas, etc.), and so has some features related to [category theory](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/categories/).

Comment: so does Axiom (FriCAS). Though I doubt if either SAGE or Axiom will do what OP asks.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try:

1. a [GAP](https://www.gap-system.org/) package called [CAP](https://www.gap-system.org/Packages/cap.html), which is part of the [homalg](https://homalg-project.github.io/homalg_project/) system.
2. [Cateno](https://github.com/jasonmorton/Cateno)

-- Mike

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's better that I answer this question, since I posed it to ineff yesterday. I let him ask the question since he is definitely more keen on the subject :) the following explanation is the best I was able to write. Sorry if it seems (and in fact it is) the product of a really simple-minded programmer!

What I had in mind was to write down a simple (?) program helping me to avoid embarassingly elementary questions like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/418506/is-this-equality-in-a-double-category-true), which turn out to be blatantly trivial once you drew the right diagram.

But now suppose that diagrams can't help you (e.g. suppose they become *really* huge), and you can only trust bare computations. You have to check whether

`{something complicated} = {something even more complicated},`

or you wrote "1" in a really complicated fashion and you want to "reduce" it in a suitable sense, with respect to some suitable algebraic laws[2].

Now what I want is to define a "type" `Object` and a "type" (or a structure? I don't remember almost anything about these topics :) ) `Arrow` (or 1-cell), where an "arrow" consists of a triple `{D,C,f}`, where $D,C$ are objects, the domain and codomain of the arrow $f$[3]. The collection of 1-cells come equipped with two (in fact, three) maps `Object source(Arrow f)`, `Object target(Arrow f)` and `int Name(Arrow f)`, doing what you expect they do. Arrows can be composed if the domain of the one coincides with the codomain of the other (and I think that the problem reduces to the implementation of this operation and the definition of its rules -label a special arrow as the identity, how do you cope with commutative-square-like situations?).

A 2-cell consists now of a square
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
A &\to&B \\
\downarrow&\alpha&\downarrow\\
C&\to & D
\end{array}
$$
having horizontal and vertical source and target:

- The horizontal source of $\alpha$ is the arrow $A\to C$;
- The vertical source of $\alpha$ is the arrow $A\to B$;
- ...
- vertical and horizontal source and target are linked by suitable relations: $s(s_v(\alpha))=s(s_h(\alpha))$, $t(s_v(\alpha))=s(t_h(\alpha))$, etc.

Notice that "natural transformations" arise as those 2-cells having identity arrows as horizontal domain and codomain. I think the most naive way to describe a 2-cell is by an inductive argument (exploiting again internalization): $\alpha$ is a structure consisting of a 4-tuple of arrows, such that "they form a square": `Arrow Vsource(Nat alpha)`, `Arrow Hsource(Nat alpha)`, `Arrow Vtarget(Nat alpha)` and `Arrow Htarget(Nat alpha)` are given in such a way that the former relations are satisfied.

2-cells can now be composed horizontally ($\boxminus$) and vertically ($\circ$), and I would like to

- Define these compositions and impose the interchange law
- Recover the "whiskering" operation $\alpha*F$ of a 2-cell $\alpha$ and a 1-cell $F$ as horizontal composition of an identity two cell with another composable 2-cell
- Do computations! Suppose now you want to check *without any graphical help* whether $\theta\circ ((\alpha * F)\boxminus (\gamma\circ \beta)\boxminus (H* \delta))=$something. You feed your program with something like

`Vcomp(theta , etc.)`

you cross your fingers and then you hopefully get something you can more easily compare with what you desire (the identity 2-cell, an endomorphism of a suitable 1-cell, ...).

====

[2] yup, *I know* that computationally speaking I'm asking first to run for a km or two and then to climb the Karakorum, but let me get to the point.

[3] which is an element of a suitable alphabet: this is not minimal since I can deduce objects from identity arrows, but I feel more comfortable in this way. Suppose for example you are labeling arrows $A\to B$ with positive-integer labels